# Creating a digest with digest.bat exits with JRE_HOME not configured

Tags: windows, tomcat, environment-variables, java, digest

I am attempting to create a digest for some passwords.

When running the following command

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\bin> digest.bat -a SHA-256 somepassword
```

i receive the following error

```
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

The value of JRE_HOME is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

I have tried `.;` at the front `\bin` at the back (with and without a semicolon and/or trailing backslash) and still the problem persists.

1. The version of tomcat is 7.0.34
2. The version of java is jre7
3. The OS is Win7 Pro 64 bit

My next step is to install a different version of the JRE and try again so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tool-wrapper.bat* file, that is referenced from inside the *digest.bat*:

```
rem   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
rem                   Using JRE_HOME instead works as well.
rem
rem   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
rem                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
rem                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
```

In other words, just set the **JAVA_HOME** to point to **JDK** (not JRE) installation and all will work just fine (tested it on my machine).

Example *JAVA_HOME* from my machine:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
```

---

**UPDATE**

From the *running.txt* file located in the Tomcat directory:

> (3) Configure Environment Variables
>
> Tomcat is a Java application and does not use environment variables.
>   **The variables are used by the Tomcat startup scripts.** The scripts use
>   the variables to prepare the command that starts Tomcat.
>
> (3.1) **Set CATALINA_HOME (required)** and CATALINA_BASE (optional)
>
> The CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE environment variables are used to
>   specify the location of Apache Tomcat and the location of its active
>   configuration, respectively.
>
> The CATALINA_HOME environment variable should be set as defined in
>   (2.2) above. The Tomcat startup scripts have some logic to set this
>   variable automatically if it is absent (based on the location of the
>   script in Unixes and on the current directory in Windows), but this
>   logic might not work in all circumstances.
>
> The CATALINA_BASE environment variable is optional and is further
>   described in the "Multiple Tomcat Instances" section below. If it is
>   absent, it defaults to be equal to CATALINA_HOME.
>
> (3.2) **Set JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME (required)**
>
> The JRE_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JRE that is
>   used to start Tomcat.
>
> The **JAVA_HOME** variable is used to specify location of a JDK. **It is
>   used instead of JRE_HOME.**
>
> Using **JAVA_HOME provides access to certain additional startup options
>   that are not allowed when JRE_HOME is used.**
>
> If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used.

Additional reading: [Tomcat: kick start](http://books.google.ee/books?id=G6-nAJiUAIMC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=setting+%22catalina_home%22+on+%22windows%22&source=bl&ots=N_OZQ0FQ-K&sig=IGF8bO660HfR3vUrlwReHsaBnsU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HglvUf6bDs2M0wWztoGgDg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwADgK)

Comment: No, in the PATH, you should put: `JAVA_HOME/bin` to be able to call java.exe, javac.exe etc from the *bin* without specifying the full path. But for the *JAVA_HOME* make new **system variable**, write in the *Variable name*: **JAVA_HOME**, in the *Variable value*: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17**

Comment: I just tried your advice and set 

JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10

no luck

Comment: @user2126755 Strange. It works on my machine just fine. Have you made *JAVA_HOME* a **system variable**?

Comment: @user2126755 The common way is making it system variable, and the also adding *JAVA_HOME/bin* to the *PATH* system variable. And it must work. Check out this picture (just the path to JDK is not standard, but you'll get the point): http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/2.0/docs/setting-java-home.html

Comment: its odd because I can run both the compiler and the jvm from the command line

Comment: @user2126755 Oh, by the way, have you also set *CATALINA_HOME* env variable to point to your Tomcat installation folder, maybe this will help you

Comment: update: I have deleted the JAVA_HOME user variable and recreated it as a system variable and set the last entry in "PATH" to be ";JAVA_HOME\bin". The problem is persisting.

Comment: @user2126755 See the update in my answer. NB! Set **CATALINA_HOME** to the root folder where your Tomcat is resided. Example: http://yellow-jbox.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-set-catalinahomepath-variables.html

Comment: Okay so after doing all the things mentioned in your answer and restarting the computer I can now run digest.bat successfully. Thanks a million!!!!